# Golub-Kahan-Lanczos Bidiagonalization Procedure implementation doesn't produce bidiagonal matrix

Tags: python, numerics, svd

I'm trying to implement the aforementioned procedure using [this website](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node198.html) as a reference. At the end of the page the algorithm is described as follows:
[image]

I think I've mapped the given algorithm to code correctly. However when I use the U and V obtained in the procedure to compute $U^{T}AV$ I don't get a bidiagonal matrix. The values along the diagonals indeed are the ones computed within the procedure but the rest of the values are not zeros. Here's my code:

```
def golub_kahan(a):
  n = a.shape[1]
  v = np.ones(n, dtype="float32") / np.sqrt(n)
  u = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype="float32")
  beta = 0
  U, V = np.zeros_like(a, dtype="float32"), np.zeros((n,n), dtype="float32")

  for i in range(n):
    V[:, i] = v
    u = a @ v - beta * u
    alpha = np.linalg.norm(u)
    u /= alpha
    U[:, i] = u
    v = a.T @ u - alpha * v
    beta = np.linalg.norm(v)
    v /= beta

  return U, V
```

I'm not sure where my mistake is, did I misunderstand the algorithm somehow?

Comment: Your algorithm is correct, but due to rounding errors you may see small entries outside the bidiagonal, instead of exact zeros. These values are about `1e-16` times as large as the other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This algorithm suffers from similar numerical stability problems as the 
symmetric Lanczos tridiagonalization algorithm, 
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm#Numerical_stability)

In exact arithmetic, after $k$ steps the following holds: $U_k^T U_k =I$, $V_k^T V_k =I$,
and $U_k^T A V_k = B_k$, where $B_k$ is the bidiagonal matrix with diagonal elements $\alpha_i$ and superdiagonal elements $\beta_i$. 
However, in floating point arithmetic, even for modest $k$, the matrices 
$U_k$ and $V_k$ may become far from orthogonal. 
Moreover, $U_k^* A V_k$ may have relatively large entries not only on the bidiagonals, 
but also at positions far away from the diagonal.
Nevertheless, the largest singular value of $B_k$ is often a quite good approximation of 
the largest singular value of $A$, even for relatively small $k$.

A much more stable bidiagonalization algorithm is the Householder bidiagonalization
algorithm, which is described in Paragraph 5.4.8 of *Matrix computations* by *Golub and 
Van Loan, 4th edition*. This method uses Householder reflections
to bidiagonalize matrix $A$, which is relatively expensive but also very stable.

It is possible to improve the Lanczos bidiagonalization algorithm,
and to maintain the orthogonality, 
by [reothogonalization](https://tidsskrift.dk/daimipb/article/view/7070/)
See also: [Some remarks on bidiagonalization and its 
implementation](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/mweb/download/publi/Ples2006.pdf).
Note that Lanczos bidiagonalization only needs matrix vector products with $A$ and $A^T$,
while the Householder bidiagonalization algorithm needs explicit access to the matrix entries of $A$, which is a disadvantage

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've modified the algorithm to use double precision and now it seems to be good enough for my purposes. Now I want to use QR algorithm applied to a symmetric matrix the way it's described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695093/using-qr-algorithm-to-compute-the-svd-of-a-matrix) but when I use my implementation of QR algorithm the results are all close to 0 (around 1e-14). When i use `np.eigvals` instead of my implementation the positive eigenvalues indeed match the singular values computed using `np.svd` on the original matrix.

Comment: Here's how I've implemented the algorithm https://pastebin.com/4dtdfurm . It seems that this approach is too naive, I was unable to find an alternative implementation that was understandable to me.

Comment: Probably you are mixing up the QR method and the QR factorization. The QR factorization (scipy.linalg.qr) is a factorization of the form $A=QR$, with $Q$ orthogonal and  $R$ upper triangular. The $QR$ factorization does not compute the eigenvalues. The [QR method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) (scipy.linalg.schur) computes a factorization of the form $A=U T U^H$, with a unitary $U$ (or orthogonal $U$ if $A$ is real symmetric), and $T$ upper triangular. The eigenvalues of $A$ are on the diagonal of $T$.